# removing commandBar from outlook inspector using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

This is my code from this code i am succesfully adding button in Microsoft outlook inspector  but when new mail open in outlook inspector (by double clicking in inbox) button sccesfully adding but if i click same main again then two button adding in outlook inspector so before calling event i want to remove  or delete previous button

How to remove button from Inspector ?

```
Private Sub inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector) Handles inspectors.NewInspector

    Try
   Private MenuBar As Office.CommandBar    
   Private ButtonOne As Office.CommandBarButton

        Dim mailItem As outlook.MailItem = TryCast(Inspector.CurrentItem, outlook.MailItem)
        If Not (mailItem Is Nothing) Then
            Try

                MenuBar = Inspector.CommandBars.Add("Mail", Office.MsoBarPosition.msoBarTop, False, True)
                MenuBar.Visible = True
                MenuBar.Protection = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoBarProtection.msoBarNoCustomize

                ButtonOne = MenuBar.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, , , , True)
                'ButtonOne.Caption = "Archive"
                'ButtonOne.Tag = "My Button"
                Dim newIcon As Icon = My.Resources.iiMS_32x32
                Dim newImageList As New ImageList
                newImageList.Images.Add(newIcon)
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(newImageList.Images(0), False)
                With ButtonOne
                    .Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonIconAndCaption
                    .Caption = ButtonCaption
                    .FaceId = 65
                    .Tag = menuTag
                    ButtonOne.PasteFace()
                End With

                Try
                    AddHandler ButtonOne.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
                Catch ex As Exception
                    writelog("Error Occured in preview windows while adding a Handler, Error: " & ex.Message)
                    MessageBox.Show("Application Error, Please Check Error Log", strCaption, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                End Try

            Catch ex As Exception
                writelog(ex.Message)
                writelog(ex.StackTrace)
            End Try
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        writelog(ex.Message)
        writelog(ex.StackTrace)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach for these situations is to implement an Inspector Wrapper.  That way you have a dedicated instance of each open item window and can separately track control states and visibility.  You would still need to add logic that either detects or adds the toolbar controls you want to work with.  See:

Developing an Inspector Wrapper for Outlook 2010
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff973716.aspx